# Most Efficient Method of Storing a List in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, vb.net, mysql-workbench

I'm relatively new to databases and MySQL, but I'm using it to connect a database to a program I've made in VB.NET. Along with many programming languages, I understand SQL, but I have very little experience with databases. Also, I'm using **MySQL Workbench** (if it helps to know).

I am creating a program which retrieves information from the database. This program in particular is a guide for cooking.

## The Database

My database consists of **one table** named *"recipes"*. Within the table are **four columns**, each named (in order):  *ID, Recipe Name, Origin, Ingredients.*

My only problem is I plan on storing around 80 or so recipes within the database; however, this will not be a difficult task because I'm simply copy-and-pasting from a Wikia page.

## The Problem

The Wikia page in which I'm copying my *ingredients* from are in a numerical list, therefor I cannot simply copy nearly ten steps, and past them into my *ingredients* column because it will not let you (typing it would take ages as well). This an issue because I need to retrieve all the ingredients in a list, and I thought it would be inefficient to create over ten different columns.

### Conclusion

Is there a more efficient way to store a list of items rather than creating multiple columns? How can I combat this issue?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Thanks for your carefully thought out question. The table you described is known as "denormalized" in database parlance. These work OK, but not optimally. You may want to read up on "normalized" databases, entities, and relationships.

Comment: @OllieJones, Thanks for the suggestion. Do you have have articles in particular that may be of use to me? Or should I just google "Normalized databases"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have multiple tables. Have a table of recipies with acolumns ID, Recipe Name and Origin, and aother table of ingredients which contains ID, Recipe ID and ingredient (ie, one row per recipe per ingrediant).

You initial ideas (ie, either all ingredients in one column, or many columns, one for each ingredient) would be inefficient and also difficult to interrogate. For example finding which recipes contained a particular ingredient would be difficult.

Comment: How could I link the recipes to a meal within the initial table?

Comment: There is no mention of meal anywhere in the question. If you mean linking ingredients to recipes then each row on the ingredients table stores the id of the recipe that they belong to (ie, Recipe ID).

Comment: thanks, that is what I meant. I will have to figure out how to do that now.

Comment: @user3357160 - Another consideration is that many recipes share the same ingredients.  You probably don't want sugar to be in your ingredients table 100 times for 100 different recipes.  You might consider revising your ingredient table to not include the recipe id and instead create a third table called RecipeIngredient which only contains the recipe id and the ingredient id.  In this way, you only need store sugar in the ingredient table once and multiple recipes can use it.  This is called a many to many relationship.